# Change Button Text dynamically when creating Alert Dialog android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, layout-inflater

Hi i want to change Alert Dialog Button text when creating alert Dialog dynamically.It means i have Boolean value based on that Boolean value need to change alert dialog button text and layout of alert dalog.Ex:- If value is true there should be one button in alert Dialog with button text "YES" and if false the need to add two button and one of the button text should change to "OK" and another button is negative button.This should be check before creating alert Dialog.So far i have change the Text and layout weight when creating alert dialog.But it did't change anything.Always show the alert dialog which in default xml file.

```
 View dialogView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_layout);
        Button btnYes = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
       if(value){
            view.setWeightSum(1);        
            btnYes.setText(R.string.yes_text);            
        }else {
            view.setWeightSum(2);
            btnYes.setText(R.string.ok_text);            
        }

           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(MyActivity.this,
                R.style.OurTheme)).setView(dialogView);
        Dialog = builder.create();
        Dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

First Create your layout `R.layout.dialog_layout` with two button, and set the both button weight of 1 i.e`android:layout_weight="1"` if your value is **true** then hide the **No** button i.e only show the single button if value is **false** then change the text dynamically as you want

```
View dialogView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button_layout);
    Button btnYes = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
    Button btnNo = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
   if(value){
         btnNo.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
        btnYes.setText(R.string.yes_text);            
    }else {

        btnYes.setText(R.string.ok_text); 
       btnNo.setText(R.string.no_text); 
    }

       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(MyActivity.this,
            R.style.OurTheme)).setView(dialogView);
    Dialog = builder.create();
    Dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i created custom layout for AlertDailog, if it suits for you use this.

**custom_alert_dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alert_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Alert Title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="19sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/alert_title"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Your Message here"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_holder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/positive_btn_holder"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/positive_btn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="OK" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/negative_btn_holder"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/negative_btn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Cancel" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my activity i used this line to show AlertDialog,

```
showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, false);



/**
 * Inside this method the alert dialog buttons are displayed based on category - param. Which is a boolean variable.
 * @param mAppContext
 * @param category - boolean
 */
private void showAlertDialog(Context mAppContext, boolean category) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mAppContext);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView alert_title = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.alert_title);
    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
    LinearLayout negative_btn_holder = (LinearLayout) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.negative_btn_holder);
    LinearLayout positive_btn_holder = (LinearLayout) dialog
            .findViewById(R.id.positive_btn_holder);
    Button positive_btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.positive_btn);
    Button negative_btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.negative_btn);
    alert_title.setText("Title...");
    // Based on your's visible and invisible the button here
    if (category == false) {
        negative_btn_holder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");

    positive_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    negative_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.I know this is what i asked But my one i have used LayoutInflater().inflate to get parent layout.But your solution doesn't use this one.Can you give me the way use LayoutInfalter to your solution.

Comment: And other thing i need to implement AlertDialog not the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

this actually looks legit. i'm not sure what is wrong with your code, maybe it's in a another part of the code.

this is a working example:

```
 public interface CompletionBlock {
    void onCompletion();
}

 public static void showYesNoDialog(Context context, String msg, String yes, String no, final View.OnClickListener yesListener, final View.OnClickListener noListener) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.yes_no_alert_layout);

    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    text.setText(Html.fromHtml(msg));

    Button yesButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
    yesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (yesListener != null)
                yesListener.onClick(v);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    if (yes != null)
        yesButton.setText(yes);

    Button noButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.noButton);
    noButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (noListener != null)
                noListener.onClick(v);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    if (no != null)
        noButton.setText(no);

    ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I need to know how to use LayoutInflater to your answer.

Comment: And also how to use AlertDialog.Builder in these scenario.